# Como convertir un formato de Fecha y hora a excel?

Tags: excel, formato

descargue una base de datos de una app, y la columna de fecha me la trae en este formato **2018-08-22T00:38:26.354Z** requiero como puedo convertirlo a un formato legible en excel.

Posdata, No conozco ningún lenguaje de programación.

Comment: ese formto se conoce como ["Zulu time" (UTC)](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiempo_universal_coordinado) como pasas de la db al excel? o es en el excel que aparece así?

Comment: Bienvenido a stackoverflow, te recomiendo que te des una vuelta por: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-askm para que aprendas a como realizar preguntas, Sin embargo, en vista de tu situación a cerca de que no conoces ningún lenguaje de programación, te recomiendo primero realices una búsqueda (No aquí, busca tutoriales, hay un sinfín) y comiences a aprender de alguno.

Answer (score 0):

Bienvenido a SO en español. Solo has puesto un ejemplo de como vienen las fechas, así que quizás no te sirva del todo, pero vamos a probar.

Yo lo he dividido todo en columnas por facilidad, pero podrías concantenarte todo en una única fórmula si quisieras y ponerle formato fecha y hora para ver el resultado final.

Bien, tu problema principal son la T, la Z y el punto en los segundos, ya que, salvo que tu Excel sea anglosajón, seguramente tu separador decimal sea la coma y no el punto.

Yo me he dividido los datos en 3 columnas. En la primera obtengo la posición de la letra T con la siguiente fórmula:

`=ENCONTRAR("T";C2;1)`

En la segunda columna, extraigo todo el texto desde el primer carácter hasta una posición antes a donde se encuentre la letra T, y lo convierto en fecha. Utilizo la siguiente fórmula:

```
=TEXTO(IZQUIERDA(C2;D2-1);"dd/mm/aaaa")
```

Con esto ya tendríamos en una columna lo que es la fecha.

Ahora, en la tercera columna obtendremos la hora. Extraemos todo el texto desde una posición después de la letra T hasta el final de la cadena de texto menos 1 (para excluir la Z). En esa extracción, reemplazamos el punto por una coma, para que Excel lo reconozca como un número con decimal, y lo convertimos a formato hora. Las fórmulas usadas son:

`=TEXTO(REEMPLAZAR(EXTRAE(C2;D2+1;LARGO(C2)-D2-1);9;1;",");"hh:mm:ss")`

Y así obtenemos la hora. Ya el resto depende de cómo quieras los datos. Si los quieres en la misma celda, por ejemplo, suma ambas columnas y ponles formato `dd/mm/aaaa hh:mm:ss`. Yo lo hecho así en la cuarta columna para obtener el resultado final y que Excel me lo reconozca como fecha:

Te pongo un pantallazo de los resultados:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Más información de las funciones que he utilizado para tratar los datos:

> [Función
>   REEMPLAZAR](https://support.office.com/es-es/article/reemplazar-y-reemplazarb-funciones-reemplazar-y-reemplazarb-8d799074-2425-4a8a-84bc-82472868878a)
>
> [Función
>   ENCONTRAR](https://support.office.com/es-es/article/encontrar-y-encontrarb-funciones-encontrar-y-encontrarb-c7912941-af2a-4bdf-a553-d0d89b0a0628)
>
> [Función
>   TEXTO](https://support.office.com/es-es/article/texto-funci%C3%B3n-texto-20d5ac4d-7b94-49fd-bb38-93d29371225c)
>
> [Función
>   IZQUIERDA](https://support.office.com/es-es/article/izquierda-e-izquierdab-funciones-izquierda-e-izquierdab-9203d2d2-7960-479b-84c6-1ea52b99640c)
>
> [Función
>   EXTRAE](https://support.office.com/es-es/article/extrae-y-extraeb-funciones-extrae-y-extraeb-d5f9e25c-d7d6-472e-b568-4ecb12433028)
>
> [Función
>   LARGO](https://support.office.com/es-es/article/largo-y-largob-funciones-largo-y-largob-29236f94-cedc-429d-affd-b5e33d2c67cb)